# Not able to create list of YT.players

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube-iframe-api

I am currently have a page with multiple YT.players, which all has to use the same Event callback.  I seem to run into a problem that only the first YT.player, where i can pause and play the video using console with commands like 
`window.player["id"].pauseVideo()`
Where other i have to do it in a "subvariable" 
`window.player["id"].j.pauseVideo()`

I somehow concluded that my way of storing them might have been wrong, so now I am trying somewhat from the beginning

https://jsfiddle.net/anita_SO/tagq4nvc/

I am in this JSfiddle trying to trigger `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()`
when someone click something in the `<div id = playerwrap></div>`
`onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()` should be called, creating all the YT.players on the site, but for some reason does this not work, I am not getting any alert message when i start the video, unfortunately?

Answer (score 0):

I think that is not the way `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` function works.

In the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=en) says:

- **`onYouTubeIframeAPIReady`** – **The API will call this function when the page has finished downloading the JavaScript for the player API**, which enables you to then use the API on your page. Thus, this function might create the player objects that you want to display **when the page loads**.

Also - in your code - you're setting the values directly to the `iframes`, but the documentation apply the configuration to a single `div` element.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MauricioSOes/d8e5bygo/) that you can use for try load more than one iframe using the YouTube Player API.

If check the jsfiddle I posted and check the console of your browser *(F12 developer tools)*, you'll see that only one div is loaded with the YouTube iframe, but the second div is not.